# Messi box jQuery plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I downloaded the plugin and added it as a separate file in my html, I also added the css file in the head, but it is not working. my html is this:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Click Sign Up!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="signupstyle.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"        href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="messi.css" />

</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="line_break" >Why is my name required?</a><br><br>
</body>
```

and my script is this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/messi.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/place.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqueryUI.js"></script>
```

they said I should call it like this:

```
$( "#line_break" ).click(function(){
  messi.alert('This is an alert with Messi.');
```

I even added the $(document).ready(function(){}) and it still didn't work.

there website: http://marcosesperon.es/apps/messi/

my reason for using messi dialog box is because it has a better look than the jquery ui dialog box and can be customized to fit my liking. If this is a waste of time please tell me and recommend something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're loading messi.js before you're loading jquery.

Since messi is a jQuery plugin, you need to load your scripts in the right order.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/messi.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/place.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqueryUI.js"></script>
```